# CSS to Make div stay on top and make other div not move when it is slideToggled

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created a jsfiddle file for you to have a look at what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/CW23N/5/

Basically, my problem is that the "#results" div keeps on moving when the "#option" div comes in. I want it to stay in the same place, and make sure the options div is on top of it, so that it kind of overhangs.

I've tried modifying the z-indexes of both div's and I've messed around with various "position" settings for all the divs. I'm not quite sure where to go now :/.

This is more of a CSS question than anything I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<div id="selector" style="position:relative;">
    Click Me! I'm a dropdown!
    <div id="options" style="position:absolute;">
        <li>Option 1 - Click Me Too!</li>
        <li>Option 2 - Click Me Too!</li>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="results">
    After you click an option, this results box will show. 
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**: There was a slight error with the JavaScript

please refer to the solution here: [Fiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/96Aya/8/)

Comment: Basically, the javascript issue was that you have the `$("li").click(...)` has to either `return false;` or it has to `stopEventPropagation`